# Programmatically change class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to increase/decrease a number contained in a class name of an element.

Let's consider this code :

```
<a href="#" class="increase">Increase</a>
<a href="#" class="decrease">Decrease</a>
<div id="my_div" class="large-12 columns">Div content</div>
```

I would like to achieve something like this :

```
$('a.decrease').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#my_div').decreaseClass('class^=large-'); 
    //decrease the number at the end of the class(es)
    //starting with the name "large-"
    //in this case large-12 would go to large-11
});
```

Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: This would involve pretty simple string manipulation and then using addClass/removeClass.  Have you not made an attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: I can't think straight anymore at this hour :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

I refined the jQuery plugin to improve its functionality. There we have an `.alterClass()` method to increase/decrease the number of class (by `step` config):

```javascript
;(function ($) {
    $.fn.alterClass = function (cls, opt) {
        opt = opt || {};
        var conf = $.extend({}, {
            'min': 1,  // min number of the class
            'max': 12, // max number of the class
            'step': 1  // increment/decrement step
        }, opt);

        return this.each(function () {
            var oldClass = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function (v, i) {
                return v.indexOf(cls) === 0;
            }).join(),
                oldNum = Number(oldClass.split('-')[1]),
                newClass;

            oldNum += conf.step;

            if (conf.step > 0) { // increase mode
                newClass = cls + (oldNum <= conf.max ? oldNum : conf.max);
            } else { // decrease mode
                newClass = cls + (oldNum >= conf.min ? oldNum : conf.min);
            }

            if (! $(this).hasClass(newClass)) {
                $(this).removeClass(oldClass).addClass(newClass);
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

You could set the `min` and/or `max` numbers and the `step` as well:

```javascript
$('.increase').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#my_div').alterClass('large-', {'step': 1});
});

$('.decrease').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#my_div').alterClass('large-', {'step': -1});
});
```

Here is the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/LQPh6/42/)**.

### Original Answer

Here's my attempt to create the `.decreaseClass()` method:

```javascript
;(function($) {
    $.fn.decreaseClass = function(cls) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var oldClass = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
                return v.indexOf(cls) === 0;
            }).join(),
                oldNum = oldClass.split('-')[1];
            $(this).removeClass(oldClass).addClass(cls+--oldNum);
        });
    };  
}(jQuery));
```

You could use the above plugin as follows:

```javascript
$('.decrease').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#my_div').decreaseClass('large-');
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/LQPh6/40/)**.

Comment: this one does not go under 10! :)

Comment: @Piero It works, check the DOM by *Inspect element* I just didn't create CSS selectors for `large-9` and lower :)

Comment: your solution requires the order of the class name. if large-xx moves to second location, the code will not work any more.

Comment: @caoglish That's NOT true. I've used `.split(" ")` method to grab the class name. However Code speaks for itself: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/LQPh6/41/

Comment: right, sorry, I miss the fact you have define the prefix of class name. it's clever way to locate the class name. inspired

Comment: you upgrade solution is much more better than the original one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through your classes and remove the class they are at and add the class they are going to. For example:

```
for (var i = 12; i > 1; i--) {
    $('#my_div .large-'+i).removeClass('large-'+i).addClass('large-'+(i-1));
}
```

Where `#my_div` is the div you are doing this in and `large-` is the prefix. I made the assumption that if you are at large-1 you'll just stay there.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

removeClass support function, remove pattern class is very easy. so you can do in this way:

```
$('#my_div').removeClass(function(index, css) {
    return (css.match(/\blarge-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
})
```

in your case.

```
   var matchClass;
$('#my_div').removeClass(function (index, css) {
    matchClass = css.match(/\blarge-\S+/g);
    return (matchClass || []).join(' ');
});

matchClass=matchClass.map(function (item) {
    item = item.split("-");
    --item[item.length - 1];
    console.log(item);
    return item.join("-");

});


$('#my_div').addClass(matchClass.join(" "));
```

I made a example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J5h5/)

-------------Update----------

if you like plugin, you can go this way:

```
(function () {
    $.fn.riseClass = function (prefix,direct) {
        var matchClass;
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(function (index, css) {
                var regex=RegExp('\\b'+prefix+'-\\S+', "g");

                matchClass = css.match(regex);
                return (matchClass || []).join(' ');
            });

            matchClass = matchClass.map(function (item) {
                item = item.split("-");
                if (direct == "down") {
                    item[item.length - 1]--;
                } else {
                    item[item.length - 1]++;
                }

                return item.join("-");

            });

            $(this).addClass(matchClass.join(" "));

        });

    };
})();
```

check on jsfiddle: [plugin version](http://jsfiddle.net/5J5h5/7/)